# Cannot connect to AzureVM gives error as "An internal error occured"

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I tried redeploy option on azure vm.

tried to reset configuration. It gave error as failed to reset rdp configuration. Stopped and restarted 3-4 times but same issue.
I see that azure vm agent is also unresponsive.

In boot diagnostics I see an exclamation mark in image.Please help.[click to see boot diagnostics image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iviR.jpg)

Comment: Can you detach the source OS virtual disk, and recreate the VM  using the old OS disk, refer to [this](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mckittrick/how-to-rebuild-a-arm-vm-from-an-existing-os-disk/).

Comment: Is there any update on your side?

Answer (score 0):

There must be some network configuration issue, try to reset network config of VM using portal and do cross check with your VNet too.

Answer (score 0):

Just changed IP address of my VM.
I was able to connect after that.
Thanks for your replies.